# How to find out where a value is set at runtime?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I realise this might be impossible but here goes anyway..

I am trying to debug some unfamiliar code in a web app without much luck.  At runtime the code is translating a particular text string in the UI to another, this is deliberate and by design but I can't find where this is happening (its a large solution of many layers of spaghetti code).
I have used watches and conditional breakpoints before but without knowing where to start they are not much use.

All I do know is what the text string is before and after the code changes it, but not what variables, objects or methods are involved.
So is it possible to use a brute force technique against every variable to break or log when it equals this string?

In a sense, a conditional breakpoint where the condition is `AnyObject.ToString()="target string"`

Or perhaps a breakpoint or watch on System.Object or System.String would do the trick, is that possible?

Comment: Can you find all references by using right click in visual studio? Or are you using reflection somewhere in your code.

Comment: Can you determine if it's a `Public` variable?

Comment: @viveknuna Find all references will only show me where methods are defined and used not values of objects

Comment: If you're dealing with a variable, is there any possibility of replacing it with a property and then placing a breakpoint on the setter?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I don't know what the variable is.  That's what I'm trying to find out.  I only know the value.

Comment: But where are you getting the value from?  It must be from somewhere.  Or are you just seeing it in the UI?

Comment: @CrushSundae It could be a public variable in class, but I need to look across multiple classes and namespaces

Comment: I'm not sure how feasible this suggestion is, but maybe you can use Mono.Cecil to go through all methods in your assembly and inject some logging call if there's a statement setting the value you're looking for

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am seeing it in the UI.  The app does this in many other places too, it translates words from one language to another on the fly.  But the routine I thought was doing it in this particular part of the UI is not where it is happening.  
I often use a brute force 'Find In Files' when trying to find static text or definitions in the code, was hoping there might be something similar for runtime values

Comment: Another suggestion: you can try using the .NET reflector VS extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/95789cdb-08f9-4dae-9b2f-fc45a452ad77 and see if you can breakpoint in String or Object (PS. I didn't use the extension so not sure if it can do that, but looks like it from the description)

Comment: @KMoussa that is a great suggestion and a very powerful tool, but it looks like because Strings are immutable and don't have a constructor there's no where in particular to place a break point to catch a specific string being used in the act

Comment: @userSteve what UI tech are you using? e.g. WPF, WinForms, views with HtmlHelpers in MVC?

Comment: If this string isn't a constant, it's very likely created in a `StringBuilder` somewhere. If you've set up [framework source debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc667410), you could set a conditional breakpoint on the final statement of `StringBuilder.ToString()` (the easiest way to do this is by setting a function breakpoint on `StringBuilder.ToString`, running the code and then refining the breakpoint). Beware that this can slow down execution tremendously.